# SQL truncate table error at -U

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, truncate

I want to run the following but I get an error at the '-' in front of 'U'

`sqlcmd -U foo -P Bar -S server -D db -Q "use db truncate table Table1"`

Thanks for the help

EDIT:

`TRUNCATE TABLE table1`

Does not work as it says I do not have permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is correct - except that `-D` should be `-d` - but you didn't post the exact error so it isn't entirely clear what's wrong. However, I think you might be executing your sqlcmd command in Management Studio; doing that gives me this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near 'U'.

But sqlcmd.exe is a command-line tool, so you should execute it from a command prompt, not from SSMS (please note that [SQLCMD mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833281%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) in SSMS is not the same thing as running sqlcmd.exe from the command line).

Comment: Ok, yea, you got the error right. Thanks for clearing that up for me.

Answer (score 0):

Specified the location of my table with

`TRUNCATE TABLE server.db.table1`

Comment: If someone else has a way to fix my original statement I will accept that in the event it works for me.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

sqlcmd -U foo -P Bar

Should be sqlcmd -Ufoo -PBar  no space.